# how to enable https proxy on squid3?

Tags: linux, ssl, https, proxy, squid

I want to do https_proxy via squid.

what i say "https_proxy" is not visiting https websites through http proxy,  I mean between proxy server and I , the line must use https(even visiting http website)

And I dont care what protocal/scheme it is between real website and proxy server

I know that I have to download source and `./configure --enable-ssl` complie

After that ,I found when I run squid3 with `https_port 443 cert=/usr/local/etc/certs/squid.cert key=/xxx`  in squid.config , there is no error (if thereis no `--enable-ssl` ,adding the `https_port` into the config file will result in error msg) , which I guess I have done the right step

How ever , the port I specified was not in `netstat -anp` , I guess there is something else to do.

So what is the problem?